# How to make correct docx after working with it as zip archive?

Tags: ms-word, zip, d, docx, winrar

I need to open docx file as zip archive, find text from `word/document.xml`, than replace some strings and put it's back to docx.

The problem that after this manipulation Word is claim that it's incorrect docx, but if I push "try to recover document" it's open normally.

If I take `word/document.xml` from archive and put it's back with WinRAR it's open totally correct.

I can't figure the reasons. I tried to make binary diff of two files, but there are a lot of difference and I can't understand which section is ok and witch is wrong.

I am using [this](http://code.dlang.org/packages/archive) archive module.

Here is my code (if it's help):

```
string doc_xml_content;
string result_xml;

auto archFile = new ZipArchive(std.file.read(zipFullName));
auto document_xml_file = archFile.getFile("word/document.xml");
// getting file content
doc_xml_content = cast(string)document_xml_file.data;

result_xml = doc_xml_content;

// document.xml in memory
auto document_xml_result = new ZipArchive.File("word/document.xml");
document_xml_result.data = result_xml;
//writeln(result_xml);
// remove old
archFile.removeFile("word/document.xml");
archFile.addFile(document_xml_result);

std.file.write("my1.docx", cast(ubyte[])archFile.serialize());
```

[docx files](http://rghost.ru/download/7KRlW6Ldv/6251d6a3f598b090e654563401a953478c0276f5/6251d6a3f598b090e654563401a953478c0276f5/docxGen.zip)

Answer (score 0):

> I am using [this](http://code.dlang.org/packages/archive) archive module.

And it or your code (probably last line, where you save archive) produces broken files. Looks like Word is able to restore those non-critical parts of the document, so that's why it opens when you click `try to recover document`.

[image: 7zip archive test]